# Azure Dev Ops Pipeline trigger on user?

Tags: c#, build, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have set up multiple release pipelines to publish a web app to my server but now I want to trigger certain pipelines only with branches from a specific user.

Is this possible? I have so far been unable to find how this is done and the only filtering I can see is on a specific branch, which is a problem for me because I’m constantly adding and removing branches as features are completed and committed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to trigger certain pipelines only with branches from a specific
>   user.

For this issue , I am afraid it is not possible in azure devops. There is currently no such trigger in the release pipeline.

The trigers for the release pipeline are described in this official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/triggers?view=azure-devops#env-triggers).

You could submit a feature request in our [Develop Community site](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/21/index.html).
Our PM and product team will kindly review your suggestion.

You can enable the Pre-deployment approvals option in the Pre-deployment conditions and select the specific user as the approver so that the release pipeline can be deployed only through the specific approver approve.

Comment: Thanks Hugh, I have added a feature request to the list. It would be nice to have more filters other than the branch or branch name.

Answer (score 0):

Branches don't "belong" to anyone; they are simply pointers to commits. Thus, this becomes a matter of branch organization. i.e. `user/dmann/my-topic-branch`, then set the branch filter to build on `user/dmann/*`.

Comment: You mean that I have to prefix every branch name with “user/cbelt” or azure dev ops is smart enough to know what that prefix means in the pipeline settings?

Comment: Branches don't have people assigned to them. Branches are pointers to commits. The only way to specify that it's "someone's" branch is to name the branch accordingly.

Comment: Well azure dev ops can distinguish branches between “mine” and “all” so that’s what I was asking about. You’re right git natively doesn’t know this but azure dev ops does.