# Azure pipeline - continue execution only for specific user

Tags: azure-pipelines

I have a TFVS repository with continuous integration (triggers a build on check-in).

**My question:**
Is there a way to proceed with a pipeline (or stop) only if a specific user (or perhaps group of users) checks in?  If so, how can this be accomplished?  It is a rare circumstance where only certain users want their changes to be immediately published to a website, for instance.  Other users, however, make changes throughout the day, and those changes will not go live until a later time.

Saw this: [Azure Dev Ops Pipeline trigger on user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57403929/azure-dev-ops-pipeline-trigger-on-user)
and it seems like it is not possible.  I'm hoping there's some way.

Comment: Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let us know if you would like further assistance.

Comment: I plan to try it out and let you know if I have any issues - thanks so much!

Comment: How are things going? Please let us know if there is any progress.

Comment: I'm having a problem with this particular piece of code: $committer= $buildPipeline.value.author.uniqueName | Select-Object -first 1

Write-Host This is latest committer: $committer  <-- in the log, $committer is coming up as blank, so I don't think it's pulling it properly from the API call.

Comment: What is your receive body when you use the REST API `GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/tfvc/changesets?api-version=5.1`? Hide your personal information.

Comment: It's fairly long but I noticed "checkedInBy" in there and uniqueName (is it possible that I just need to change committer to checkedInBy?)

Comment: {"count":1,"value":[{"changesetId":5520,"url":"https://dev.azure.com/myorg/myproduct/_apis/tfvc/changesets/5520",
"author":{"displayName":"Developer Person","url":"https://spsprodeus23.vssps.visualstudio.com..."
,"id":"GUID","uniqueName":"Developer.Person@myorg.com",
"imageUrl":""},
"checkedInBy":{"displayName":"Developer Person","url":"https://spsprodeus23.vssps.visualstudio.com/..."
,"id":"GUID","uniqueName":"Developer.Person@myorg.com","imageUrl":"https://dev.azure.com/myorg/_api/_common/identityImage?id=GUID"},
"createdDate":"2020-02-06T17:46:12.07Z"}]}

Comment: It is trimmed to fit in comment.

Comment: Also, when I just do Write-Host $buildPipeline I basically get HTML - $buildPipeline.value returns blank, so guessing that's where it becomes empty.  Is there another way to get the value?

Comment: I see the problem: looks like its not authenticating with Azure properly.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to proceed with a pipeline (or stop) only if a specific user (or perhaps group of users) checks in?

Indeed, there is no such out of box trigger only for specific user.

**As workaround**, we could use the REST API to get the committer from the latest changeset (because you are using TFVC repository):

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/tfvc/changesets?api-version=5.1
```

Then we could set different variables based on whether the value returned by the REST API is equal to our expected committer, and then add conditions to other tasks in the pipeline according to the value of the variable.

Details:

In the pipeline, we could add a `inline powershell` task with following scripts:

```
$url = "https://dev.azure.com/<OrganizationName>/<ProjectName>/_apis/tfvc/changesets?$top=1&api-version=5.1"
$buildPipeline= Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{   
 Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"
} -Method Get

$committer= $buildPipeline.value.author.uniqueName | Select-Object -first 1

Write-Host This is latest committer: $committer


  if ($committer -like "<SpecificUserAccount>")
    {
      Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=ImmediatePublish]True"
    }
```

Then we add a custom condition for others task in this pipeline based on the value of variable `ImmediatePublish`:

```
and(succeeded(), eq(variables['ImmediatePublish'], 'True'))
```

[image]

In this case, this pipeline will run every time the trigger fires, but **only when the submitter is what we expected, this pipeline will run other tasks that are actually meaningful, otherwise this pipeline will only run our inline powershell task**, it will not Have any impact on our production.

If you do not want your pipeline run every time the trigger fires, you could add a new pipeline with the inline powershell task in it, then add this pipeline as [Build completion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2018/apr-03-vsts#chain-related-builds-together-using-build-completion-triggers).

Hope this helps.